# Details View Insert and Cancel Command Not Firing from Inside a Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, detailsview

I am working on a Work Order Management Web Application .net 4.5 C# Requestor creates a Work Order once a work order is Created The Supervisor can view all work orders how ever half of the gridview data will be left blank that is because the supervisor will review the first half and then fill out the second half using a details view so all works good the users enters the details into a details view clicks submit(insert command) and the data gets added to the database and refreshed on the gridview, only when the details view was not in a panel, however the new requirement is to have the details view popup as a modal for that particular row when clicked on the + image button on gridview, enter the other details and submit they want this feature because the want more of the data on the gridview displayed on the web page:

[image]

**Details View inside a ModalPopUpExtender**

```
TargetControlID="pnl1" PopupControlID="pnl1" ></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Width="881px" Height="175px">
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="WorkOrderNum" BackColor="#39B1CC"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="175px"
Width="881px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" PostBack = "True"
oniteminserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" OnItemCommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkPerformed / PartsUsed"
SortExpression="column1">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column1") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column1") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Work Completed By " SortExpression="column2">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column2") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column2") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maint. Supv. Approval" SortExpression="column3">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column3") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column3") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Q.C. Inspection By" SortExpression="column4">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column4") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column4") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column4") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Work_Comp_Date" SortExpression="Work_Comp_Date">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Work_Comp_Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Work_Comp_Date") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date format in DD/MM/YYYY" ValidationExpression = "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$" ControlToValidate = "TextBox5"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Work_Comp_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supv_Approval_Date"
SortExpression="Supv_Approval_Date">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"
Text='<%# Bind("Supv_Approval_Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"
Text='<%# Bind("Supv_Approval_Date") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date format in DD/MM/YYYY" ValidationExpression = "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$" ControlToValidate = "TextBox6"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Supv_Approval_Date") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maint. Supv. Approval Date"
SortExpression="column5">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column5") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column5") %>' Height="29px" Width="699px"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date format in DD/MM/YYYY" ValidationExpression = "^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/.](19|20)\d\d$" ControlToValidate = "TextBox9"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("column5") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Safety_Inspected_By"
SortExpression="Safety_Inspected_By">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"
Text='<%# Bind("Safety_Inspected_By") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"
Text='<%# Bind("Safety_Inspected_By") %>'  Height="29px" Width="699px" ></asp:TextBox>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Safety_Inspected_By") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="29px" Width="699px" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField = "Status" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
<asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Complete</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Waiting For Approval</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Denied</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Cancel</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
CommandName="Update" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click1" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</EditItemTemplate>
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
CommandName="Insert" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="New" Text="New" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

: &nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Height="25px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
</asp:Panel>
```

**When the image button is clicked**

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

 {
 //DetailsView1.Visible = true;
   ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow GridView1 = (GridViewRow)imgbtn.NamingContainer;
    string workordernum = GridView1.Cells[3].Text;
    TextBox10.Text = workordernum;
   ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    DetailsView1.Visible = true;        
 }
```

My SqlSource Code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WorkOrderConnectionString4 %>"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Master] WHERE [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum"
InsertCommand="UPDATE [Master] SET [WorkPerformed / PartsUsed] = @column1, [Work Completed By :] = @column2, [Maint. Supv. Approval] = @column3, [Q.C. Inspection By:] = @column4, [Work Comp Date] = @Work_Comp_Date, [Supv Approval Date] = @Supv_Approval_Date, [Safety Inspected By] = @Safety_Inspected_By, [Status] = @Status, [Maint. Supv. Approval Date] = @column5 WHERE [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum"
SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkOrderNum], [WorkPerformed / PartsUsed], [Work Completed By :] , [Maint. Supv. Approval], [Q.C. Inspection By:], [Work Comp Date] AS Work_Comp_Date, [Supv Approval Date] AS Supv_Approval_Date, [Safety Inspected By] AS Safety_Inspected_By, [Status], [Maint. Supv. Approval Date] FROM [Master]"


UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Master] SET [WorkPerformed / PartsUsed] = @column1, [Work Completed By :] = @column2, [Maint. Supv. Approval] = @column3, [Q.C. Inspection By:] = @column4, [Work Comp Date] = @Work_Comp_Date, [Supv Approval Date] = @Supv_Approval_Date, [Safety Inspected By] = @Safety_Inspected_By, [Status] = @Status, [Maint. Supv. Approval Date] = @column5 WHERE [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox10" Name="WorkOrderNum2"
PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column2" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column3" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column4" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Work_Comp_Date" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Supv_Approval_Date" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Safety_Inspected_By" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="column5" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox10" Name="WorkOrderNum"
PropertyName="Text" />
</InsertParameters>
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox10" Name="WorkOrderNum"
PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column2" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column3" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="column4" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Work_Comp_Date" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Supv_Approval_Date" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Safety_Inspected_By" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="column5" />
<asp:Parameter Name="WorkOrderNum" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WorkOrderConnectionString3 %>"


SelectCommand="SELECT WorkOrderNum, Requestor, Date, Department, CompletionDate, MachineDescription, MachineLocation, [Type of Work Order], [Work Required], [WorkPerformed / PartsUsed], [Work Completed By :], [Maint. Supv. Approval], [Q.C. Inspection By:], [Work Comp Date], [Supv Approval Date], [Safety Inspected By], Status, [Maint. Supv. Approval Date] FROM Master ORDER BY WorkOrderNum DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**My Question is why is the submit and cancel button not firing now, it fires when out of the panel or modal, is there any settings that i need to change?**

**Also is the a way to make the background black when the popup appears, i am really new to the popup concept i was able to accomplish the below after googling alot about it**

Please Help:)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out why the Detail Views Insert and Cancel events were not firing inside the details view, All i had to do was change the UseSumbitBehavior= "False"

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Insert" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Button2_Click1" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
&nbsp;
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

As Far as Changing the Background to Black i was able to accomplish this by using some CSS:

```
<style>
.modalBackground
{
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.7;
}
.pnl1BackGround
{
    background-color:White;

}
```

To Change the Position of the PopUp i used X and Y cordinates, X to move Horizontally and Y to move Vertically.

Hope this answer helps someone out there :)
Happy Coding Guys